# nested if javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url()."homectrl/saveslide";?>">   

    <select name="inpevent" id="eventcontrol">  
    <option value="pilih">--Pilih--</option> 
    <option value="textonly">Text Only</option> 
    <option value="redirect">Redirect</option>  
    </select>   

    <select name="inpsel" id="selectcontrol">  
        <option value="pilih">--Pilih--</option> 
                      <?php   
                foreach($product->result() as $row){  
                    echo "<option value='".$row->namaproduct."'>".$row->namaproduct."</option>";  
                }  
                      ?>    


      <tr class="bgtd2" id="hidetxonly1"><td>Title</td><td id="centered">:</td><td><input type="text" name="inptitle" id="pjg" required></td></tr>  
  <tr class="bgtd1" id="hidetxonly2"><td>Description</td id="centered"><td>:</td><td><textarea name="inpdesc" id="txarea" required></textarea></td></tr>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Slide" onClick="return cekevent()">  
    </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
         function cekevent(){   
            if($("#eventcontrol").val() == "pilih"){   
                  return false;  
            }else {  
            var cek;  
                if($("#eventcontrol").val() == "redirect"){  
                    if($("#selectcontrol").val() == "pilih"){  
                         return false;
                      }else{  
                            return true;
                      }  

                 }  

           }
     }
```

when i choose value of inpsel (name of select type) that not "pilih", it didnt redirect to url in form action and do nothing. somebody can solve or teach me solve this problem ?

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here. Post the rendered output and the errors you get.

Comment: the output is didnt redirect, thats all. if the code true, it should be redirect from form action

Comment: `if($("#eventcontrol").val() == "redirect" && $("#selectcontrol").val() == "pilih")` is cleaner than nested ifs.  Of course that's if this is a complete example.

Comment: Do you just want to stop submit from firing if either of them say "--Pilih--"?

Comment: yeah, i want to stop submit from firing if either of them say "--Pilih--"

Answer (score -1):

Updated, you can combine the nested if condition as below to simply the logic.
Also, since your function is returning something. In your codes, not all base path has return statement.

```
function cekevent()
{   
        if($("#selectcontrol").val() == "pilih" || $("#eventcontrol").val() == "pilih")
        {
            return false;  
        }           
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
 }
```

Comment: the first if to check if the value not pilih in eventcontrol and the second if , is to check if value from first if is "redirect" and not "pilih" in selectcontrol